# deserialize json with objects

Tags: python, json

In python 3, how can I deserialize an object structure from json?

Example json:

```
{ 'name': 'foo',
  'some_object': { 'field1': 'bar', 'field2' : '0' },
  'some_list_of_objects': [
      { 'field1': 'bar1', 'field2' : '1' },
      { 'field1': 'bar2', 'field2' : '2' }, 
      { 'field1': 'bar3', 'field2' : '3' },
  ]
}
```

Here's my python code:

```
import json

class A:
  name: str
  some_object: B
  some_list_of_objects: list(C)

  def __init__(self, file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as json_file:
        self.__dict__ = json.load(json_file)

class B:
  field1: int
  field2: str

class C:
  field1: int
  field2: str
```

How to force `some_object` to be of type `B` and `some_list_of_objects` to be of type list of `C`?

Comment: Are these classes [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses)?

Comment: yes, they could be dataclasses

Comment: Not sure if this quite meets the criteria of a duplicate, but some interesting answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376099/python-dataclass-from-a-nested-dict).

Comment: Yes agreed, that is also why I retracted my close vote.

Comment: @Z.D. check out my updated answer below for one possible approach. There are also other equally valid solutions in the post as included above.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Curious, why was the [tag:python3] tag removed? It appears like this would ideally only be a python 3 solution - assuming dataclasses are used of course, as mentioned above.

Comment: An argument could be made that at this point, `python3` is redundant. Python 3 is Python since Python 2.7 reached end-of-life almost a year ago.

Comment: @rv.kvetch There is a specific tag for `python-dataclasses`. Read the tag description for `python-3.x` to see that it generally should not be used except for specific cases (specifically, not to be added to indicate what version the code is running as)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using Python 3, I would suggest using [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to model your classes. This should improve your overall code quality and also eliminate the need to explicltly declare an `__init__` constructor method for your class, for example.

If you're on board with using a third-party library, I'd suggest looking into an efficient JSON serialization  library like the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/) that performs implicit type conversion - for example, string to annotated `int` as below. Note that I'm using `StringIO` here, which is a file-like object containing a JSON string to de-serialize into a nested class model.

> **Note:** the following approach should work in Python 3.7+.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from io import StringIO

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


json_data = StringIO("""
{ "name": "foo",
  "some_object": { "field1": "bar", "field2" : "0" },
  "some_list_of_objects": [
      { "field1": "bar1", "field2" : "1" },
      { "field1": "bar2", "field2" : "2" },
      { "field1": "bar3", "field2" : "3" }
  ]
}
""")


@dataclass
class A(JSONWizard):
    name: str
    some_object: B
    some_list_of_objects: list[C]


@dataclass
class B:
    field1: str
    field2: int


@dataclass
class C:
    field1: str
    field2: int


a = A.from_json(json_data.read())

print(f'{a!r}')  # alternatively: print(repr(a))
```

##### Output

```
A(name='foo', some_object=B(field1='bar', field2=0), some_list_of_objects=[C(field1='bar1', field2=1), C(field1='bar2', field2=2), C(field1='bar3', field2=3)])
```

##### Loading from a JSON file

As per the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69773539/converting-a-json-file-to-a-python-class), I would discourage overriding the constructor method to pass the name of a JSON file to load the data from. Instead, I would suggest creating a helper class method as below, that can be invoked like `A.from_json_file('file.json')` if desired.

```py
    @classmethod
    def from_json_file(cls, file_name: str):
        """Deserialize json file contents into an A object."""
        with open(file_name, 'r') as json_file:
            return cls.from_dict(json.load(json_file))
```

##### Suggestions

Note that variable annotations (or annotations in general) are subscripted using square brackets `[]` rather than parentheses as appears in the original version above.

```
some_list_of_objects: list(C)
```

In the above solution, I've instead changed that to:

```
some_list_of_objects: list[C]
```

This works because using subscripted values in standard collections was introduced in [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/). However, using the `from __future__ import annotations` statement introduced to Python 3.7+ effectively converts all annotations to *forward-declared* string values, so that new-style annotations that normally only would work in Python 3.10, can also be ported over to Python 3.7+ as well.

One other change I made, was in regards to swapping out the order of declared class annotations. For example, note the below:

```py
class B:
  field1: int
  field2: str
```

However, note the corresponding field in the JSON data, that would be deserialized to a `B` object:

```
'some_object': { 'field1': 'bar', 'field2' : '0' },
```

In the above implementation, I've swapped out the field annotations in such cases, so class `B` for instance is declared as:

```py
class B:
    field1: str
    field2: int
```

Comment: thank you for the deep-dive

Comment: no problem! glad it was helpful.